# Select all elements of a specific type with a specific class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have in the html:

```
<div id="tags_list">
  <span class="label">Favorites</span>
  <span class="label label-info">Starred</span>
  <span class="label label-info">Popular</span>
</div>
```

I'm looking for the jQuery selector that will return an array of all `<span>` elements that have the class `.label-info`, and only inside the `#tags_list` div.

I'm trying something like this in the js without success:

```
var tagsList = $("#tags_list > span:class['label-info']");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$('#tags_list >span.label-info')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
var spans = $('#tags_list > span.label-info');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kVjsS/1/).

`spans` is a jQuery object, which allows you to use jQuery methods on the results. If you'd rather have DOM-nodes instead, to use native JavaScript methods, then:

```
var spans = $('#tags_list > span.label-info').get();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kVjsS/2/).

Or, in plain JavaScript:

```
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('#tags_list > span.label-info');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kVjsS/3/).

The latter options will return an array (using `get()`) and a nodeList (with `querySelectorAll()`), both of which you'll have to explicitly iterate over in order to perform actions.

References:

- [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).